# XML or SQL - Only Reading data frequently

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I have a PHP function, that returns 'true' or 'false' based on if a particular data exists in Database/XML

This search query will be performed on each page load of the website.

Which option will be better- SQL DB or data stored in XML.
Which will have less load and effect on server performance due to the high number of page loads/visits.

I don't Need to modify or Insert data, It's just searching.

Thank you

------- update --------

Another way, I was thinking is to store all information ( strings ) in form of file name. [eg-  a directory having 1000 files with different names ]
Now I can search for a particular file (eg- 457.txt ) in the directory, to see if that file exists.

```
<?php
if(file_exists('457.txt'){
echo "file exists";
}
```

How much load will it be on the server, compared to XML query & SQL query?

Main aim to see, if a particular data already exist on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have reason to be concerned about user/system load, I would argue against the XML file solution but not for the reason you think of. It's more about **concurrency**. What would happen if several processes were to update the file at the same time ? Writing to a file raises concerns about locking issues you might encounter soon enough.

The file name idea is interesting but will probably scale badly, and not allow you to perform much more than single item existence search with acceptable performance, unless you dive deep into OS, FS and storage layer intricacies. It all depends on the volume of data you intend to store and how you intend to access it.

All in one, the database is the most versatile storage solution for these kind of needs, and allows you to perform queries using an easy, explicit language, among many other advantages (ACID transactions [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID ], scalability...).

Comment: This search query will be performed on each page load of the website. So, If I use a database, then I will be creating thousands of SQL connection. A new SQL connection will be created for each page load.

Comment: Yeah, databases are meant to handle it. All dynamic websites including stackoverflow depend on this, it is linear and reliable.